# Security issue found in login system no resolved. Next Step?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, disclosure, ethics

Approximately 8 months ago I found and reported a serious security issue surrounding a website I use.  This website holds confidential and protected personally identifiable information.

I called the company's tech support who then transferred me to the development team.  I gave them very specific instructions on how to reproduce the error.  This error will allow an unauthorized person take control of a legitimate account and have access up to the limits of the compromised account.

They opened a bug report and told me they would look into it.  Approximately one month later, I get a message that the team is still looking into the situation.

Another two weeks pass and I call them to try to get an update.  Again, I'm told they are working on the issue but they cannot give me any details (which I totally understand.)

Today, I tested the vulnerability and found it is still active.

I know they are in the process of rebuilding their software.  Some of their customers can move to the new system because that part of the system is more-or-less, complete.  Other customers cannot because not all of the functionality needed is complete.

It is a requirement for me to use this software at work to store information referenced above.

I do not know what kind of trouble my employer or myself could get into if the system was compromised.

What are the ethical and legal next steps to take?

Comment: The trouble that may be faced depends on where the company and its clients are based

Comment: The company is USA based.  As I understand, the bulk of their customers are US, but they do have some customers all across the globe.

Comment: You may want to look at these links ([1](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/security/),[2](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/personal-data-breaches/)) with regards to European customers.

Comment: What kind of "next steps" are you asking about? Do you want advice on how to responsibly disclose this vulnerability? Or do you want advice on how to best protect your own data?

Comment: @Anders -- Thank you for asking the clarification.  The next step I was inquiring about is the ethical disclosure of the issue.

Comment: The edit was made by @schroeder, but I think I can explain why: He simply added the info you wrote in a comment here, and removed unecesarry parts. The culture here is to try to keep all relevant info in the question, but not include things like greetings. You can always see all edits if you click where it says "edited X hours ago".

Comment: And now I just made an edit to add the [disclosure] tag. :-)

Comment: @JimBaize "thank yous", signatures, etc are seen as noise and are edited out. You will see that in most posts here. I also removed the "Edit" as there has been no answer and we do not need to know from you that it was edited: we can see the edits you made.